# Bash : space in path access

Tags: bash, shell, path, terminal, escaping

I tried to access a specific path with a bash script but my terminal won't access to it.
Here's my very simple script :

```
#!/bin/bash
init()
{
    cd $PATH
    ls -l
}
PATH="/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users"
init
```

I tried to write "/Macintosh\ HD" without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
cd "$PATH"
```

note the quotation marks.

Comment: That's different issue, you ruined your environment by setting `PATH` to `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users`. Can you pick some other name for your variable?

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed I have to rename my variable.

Comment: You're welcome. You mentioned spaces, so at first I didn't pay much attention to the name of variable, probably assuming it's either just an example or intended value, sorry for that.

Comment: @Pete, that's why _you should never use uppercase variable names in shell scripts_, as they will, sooner or later (sooner in your case), clash with already existing variables.